# 4K monitor showing 2560x1440 as max resolution

Tags: display, resolution, displayport, high-definition, mini-displayport

I recently purchased a 4k Monitor, to figure that HDMI can only display 4K at 30 hz, which isnt enough for gaming and it simply makes it less enjoyable with the laggy input. It worked at 4k resolution with HDMI, but when I input a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort, the max resolution is 2560x1440.

Is this a Driver issue, or maybe I need to solve something in AMD Catalyst Control Panel?

Note: I have a XFX Radeon HD 7870 Black/gHz Edition.

UPDATE: Just installed latest AMD Beta Drivers, and it still shows that 2560x1440 is max resolution.

Comment: What monitor? Might be a factor here.

Comment: Samsung u28d590d, but maybe the cable is a factor, I am currently looking into that aspect

Comment: needs DisplayPort 1.2, according to AMD site - http://www.amd.com/en-gb/products/graphics/desktop/7000/7800

Comment: [Here](http://community.amd.com/community/amd-blogs/amd-gaming/blog/2014/05/05/celebrating-a-new-generation-of-ultrahd-displays)’s some more info, although it’s a press release (of sorts). So it might not be possible for your GPU.